# How to configure Nautilus so when a CD/DVD/USB is inserted it does not open another Window

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

How to configure Nautilus so that when I insert a CD, DVD, USB, etc.. it is not opened in another window but in the already opened Nautilus windows. For example like a new Nautilus window tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently possible. It would require at least one of these features to exist in Nautilus:

- The ability to automatically open removable media in new tabs. A [request for this feature](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=551682) was made in 2008 and has received no response.
- The ability to open all folders in new tabs. A [request for this feature](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus/+bug/264816) was also made in 2008, and GNOME developers have not concluded their discussion of it.
- The ability to open new tabs from the command line. There is a [proposal for this functionality](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=633338) but it has not been implemented.
- The ability to open new tabs using a D-Bus interface. According to [this post on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/140694/51778), there is no such interface.

Comment: Enough said. Well I guess waiting is the case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Install **Ubuntu Tweak**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Open the application, click on **Tweaks**, and then **Nautilus Setting**.

Under **Automatic Mount Settings**, there are some options.

**Screenshot:**
[image: Ubuntu Tweak]

Comment: Nice thought but am looking for a way to automatically open whatever I insert (CD,DVD,USB...) but instead of opening a new windows it should use the already opened Nautilus window. For example if I insert 10 CDs it should not create 10 Nautilus windows. It should use the first Nautilus window opened or create 10 tabs inside the first Nautilus window. Try to connect 4 pen drivers or insert 10 CD/DVD. After that press SUPER + W to see a whole bunch of Nautilus windows opened.